# Unable to deploy my Vite application on Elastic Beanstalk using Docker

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vite

I tried deploying my vite application on Elastic Beanstalk but got various errors. Firstly the health state is almost never ready, it stays pending and when I try to deploy the application it shows the following error.

Error: Deployment failed: Error: Status: 400. Code: InvalidParameterValue, Message: Environment named tripdocks-final-env is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.

The application works fine in my local like it always does.

I have tried it multiple times and kept receiving different Deployment Errors.

deploy-aws.yml

```
name: Deploy React Book App from GitHub to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
on:
  # activates the workflow when there is a push on the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - master_deploy
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # the OS your job should run on
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Latest Repo
        # checks out your repository under the GitHub workspace so that your workflow can access it
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate Deployment Package
        # zip all files except .git
        run: zip -r deploy.zip * -x "**.git**"

      - name: Get timestamp
        uses: gerred/actions/current-time@master
        id: current-time

      - name: Run string replace
        uses: frabert/replace-string-action@master
        id: format-time
        with:
          # replaces '[:\.]+' in the timestamp with '-'
          pattern: '[:\.]+'
          string: "${{ steps.current-time.outputs.time }}"
          replace-with: "-"
          flags: "g"

      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
        with:
          # input the credentials you used to setup AWS CLI and credentials for the application environment
          aws_access_key: "${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY }}"
          aws_secret_key: "${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}"
          application_name: application-name
          environment_name: environment-name
          version_label: "app-${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}"
          region: ap-south-1
          existing_bucket_name: tripdocksapp
          deployment_package: deploy.zip

      - name: Deployed!
        run: echo App deployed to ELB
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```